# a verb to describe an act of paying attention, but not "follow"

Tags: word-request

> She is a very attentive international student who despite her limited
> passive vocabulary **follows** each and every remark of her teacher.

In the above sentence it may look like teacher's remarks are some kind of commands or orders being given to the student, which she obediently fulfills. However, what I am trying to say is that she is simply paying attention to every word of her teacher. The problem is in the dubious meaning of the word "follows". Which word should I substitute for it in order to convey the intended meaning?

(I don't want to use "pays attention" because the word "attentive" is already used in the sentence)

Comment: [correction: *In the sentence above*]. I'd say: is able to follow, otherwise there is no contrast with limited passive vocabulary.

Comment: @Lambie - I see. Thank you!

Comment: No worries my refulgent friend. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is a re-write and not a direct answer to your question but how about

> She is a very assiduous international student who despite her limited passive vocabulary attends closely to each and every remark of her teacher.

I have avoided the repetition by replacing the attentive with assiduous.

Comment: And you have answered my question!

Answer (score 1):

The American Heritage Dictionary defines **follow** thus:

> To be attentive to; pay close heed to

*too sleepy to follow the sermon*

As you can see, the above definition of the word fits in the description you've provided quite nicely.

Comment: Well, "follow the sermon" would not give you a second thought because the sermon is not a person. However, "She followed every remark of the pastor who read the sermon" may.

Comment: I don't quite **follow** your point, @brilliant.

Comment: I mean a sermon is not a person. It can't give you a command or an order to follow. Therefore, if someone says "she followed the sermon closely" the only way to understand that phrase is that she was paying her full attention to the sermon. However, if it's a person (pastor, teacher, officer, parent, etc.), than such phrase like "she followed her mother's remarks closely" may be taken in the sense that she was acting upon every order that was coming from her mom.